# How to show different images for a single button?

Tags: flash, flex3

How to show different images for a single button?

It should show different images when the mouse pointer is over the button and out of the button.

Comment: Is this you? http://stackoverflow.com/users/702166/naveen If so, why did you create a new account.  If not; I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to show multiple images on a single button?  Or use the same class, but change the image displayed?  What did you try?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: The original question has the goal described, I don't know why @Michael Petrotta removed it. The task would be to change the icon of the button on mouse over.

Comment: @rekaszeru: I didn't remove it; our two edits stepped over each other. Thanks for letting me know; I've added it back in.

Answer (score 1):

`<mx:Button label="test" downIcon="@Embed('assets/downIcon.png')" upIcon="@Embed('assets/upIcon.png')" />`

see [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a easy way to do it. Up to know i have chosen one of the following:
1. either write your own object, where you set event handlers to swap the image
or
2. make a flash with bubbling event, and embed/load it in flex, where you catch the event (communicating between a swf from flash and flex is quite a pain, so events seem to do it)

I can provide code if you are interested in any of those two methods

UPDATE:

here's the code to the easiest way. Just add the two images:

```
 package {

 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   public class Test extends Sprite {

    [Embed(source="image1.png")]
    private var Image1:Class;
    [Embed(source="image2.png")]
    private var Image2:Class;


  public function Test() {
        var theHolderMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        addChild(theHolderMC);

        theHolderMC.addChild(new Image2());
        theHolderMC.addChild(new Image1());

        theHolderMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap)
   }

   private function swap(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var holder:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
        holder.swapChildren(holder.getChildAt(0), holder.getChildAt(1));
        // or alternatively, you can make them .visible=false or any other way you want. 
   }


}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you provide me the code.Here i am using flex3.Here i want to show different image when the mouse pointer is over the button and out side of the button.

Comment: Can you provide me main mxml file.Whether this sol is for showing different images when the mouse pointer is over the button and out of the button?

Answer (score 0):

The method you choose for this task depends on your exact circumstance. The simplest way of implementing mouseover buttons doesn't involve any code; within Flash you simply define a mouseover image in the button symbol.